# How to change the page title name as product name in magento?

Tags: magento

In my magento store have a small problem. I create one page title named as gold. In this page contain **n number of products**. If the customer click the product then change the **page title name to product name**.

Is there any possible to change it. I resolved this problem in php. But no luck in magento.

Here is the php code.

```
<?php
ob_start (); // Buffer output
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$pageTitle = 'New Test'; // Call this in your pages' files to define the page title
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
echo str_replace ('Test', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Magento you can change the Page Title like this:

```
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$headBlock->setTitle($newtitle); //set title
$headBlock->setKeywords($keywords); //set keywords
$headBlock->setDescription($description); //set description
```